# IsEnabled = false makes WPF button disappeared while using caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a button in my WPF project, which looks like this:

```
        <Button 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            x:Name="Add"
            IsEnabled="False"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="23" Width="29" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="\Resources\Pictures\Add.png"
                   Width="20" Height="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

In the corresponding ViewModel I have `Add` method and `CanAdd` property:

```
public bool CanAdd
{
   get { return true; }
}

public void Add()
{
   //some code
}
```

The problem is that when `IsEnabled` property is set to `False`, Button dissapears. I know that this is because of caliburn micro convetions. How can I modify this conventions, so that When I set `IsEnabled` to `False` button disables, and when `CanAdd` is `false` it becomes collapsed (as it is now)?

Comment: Are you sure that Caliburn.micro has a convention by which IsEnabled=false makes a button disappear ?

Comment: You could fill in your needs by using the Visibility Property

IsEnabled="False"
Visibility="{Binding CanAdd,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter }}"
cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action Add]"

A cleaner would be to bind the IsEnabled property as well, rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: @A.M: Setting IsEnabled to false shouldn't case the Button to disappear. What makes you think it does?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I defined `IsEnabled` property for this button in xaml for test purposes only. When The `CanAdd` is `false` in ViewModel, button dissapears automatically. To solve this I have to set Visibility property of the button in xaml to `Visible` and there is no need of additional properties (type of visibility) if you really don't want dissapear button in specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set `IsEnabled` to `false` in the XAML markup. The `Button` will be disabled when the `CanAdd` property returns `false` only. So if you want to disable the `Button`, you should implement your view model to return `false` from `CanAdd`. The view shouldn't decide when to enable the `Button`.

If you want to *hide* the `Button` you should either set its `Visibility` property to `Hidden` or `Collapsed` in the XAML, or bind it to either a `Visibility` source property of the view model or to a `bool` property and use a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`.

Disabling a `Button` doesn't hide it.

Comment: When I do not have defined the visibility property explicitly in xaml (or it can be done in ViewModel if needed) button dissapears when CanAdd is set to false.